# Unable to open Jupyter Notebook using CMD

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
C:\Users\PROY>jupyter notebook

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 
'"c:\users\proy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  
 "C:\Users\PROY\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook': 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have added all the necessary path to the environment variables.

Note, this is happening after I uninstalled VS Code. But still I can use it through Anaconda 3.

Comment: how about `python -m jupyter notebook`  ?

Comment: maybe check if exist `c:\users\proy\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe` and `C:\Users\PROY\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts\jupyter.exe` on disk.

Comment: Not done yet ...